# Restructuring a filled SQL database in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

- Due to bad design, I have a database that contains data in one table, that really should be split up into two tables.
- The table provides data for two different models. I distinguish between those models using a table field called `type`.
- I use this to say `if type == MODEL_A ... do foo`, or `if type == MODEL_B ... do bar`.
- Depending on the type of the concrete table (type: `MODEL_A` or `MODEL_B`), I only use a subset of the columns in the table for `MODEL_A`, and the remaining subset of the columns for `MODEL_B`. Therefore, many columns always contain `NULL`
- I believe they should be split up into a `MODEL_A` table and a `MODEL_B` table.

**How should I go about this in Rails/ActiveRecord, without dropping the existing data?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty broad question, so my answer will focus on procedure rather than specific code.

1. Create a new table for the `MODEL_B` data. Name it `MODEL_B_TABLE` (for example)
2. Rename the original table (if necessary) since it will now be used for only `MODEL_A` data
3. Run a query to pull all `MODEL_B` data from the original table and place it into the new `MODEL_B_TABLE`
4. Update your application to pull from the correct database tables
5. Remove the unneeded data from the original table (since that specific data now exists in the `MODEL_B_TABLE`)
6. Test, test, test!
7. Upload the changes to a staging server and run the migrations.
8. If all looks well on the staging server, push it to production. If not, start over from step 6.

That would be an appropriate procedure to avoid data loss for a production server. Proper testing is paramount! Ensure you make backups of all your data before pushing into production.